# Align floating elements of different height

Tags: html, css

I have a a few divs `.photo_box` that contains a div `.photo_stats_title` which holds some text. When the text starts taking up more than 1 line, the height of its parent div `.photo_box` changes. This causes the various `.photo_box` divs to be aligned by their bottom.

**Problem:** How can we get them to align by the top? *Preferably without using jQuery/Javascript*

**JSfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/ySbjQ/

[image]

Comment: following on from the answers, do you intend to show anything beneath the photos?

Comment: Yes, there will be rows of the parent divs... 4 `.photo_box` per row. Using `vertical-align: top` works well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `display: inline-block;` and `vertical-align: top` to align these.

```
.photo_box {
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px; 
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 15px;  
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ySbjQ/1/

Also, if you need support for some older browsers, check this out for some fixes http://blog.mozilla.org/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/

Answer (score 0):

add "position:absolute;" to .photo_stats_title in the CSS.

http://jsfiddle.net/ySbjQ/4/